# Timeline event error in Adobe edge runtime stops javascript execution

Tags: javascript, html, onerror, adobe-edge

I am creating a learning module for an education company where i create 25 animal sprites (canvas with an image in it) and put them in a farm (div with a background image).
The background was created in Adobe Edge for the sake of the opening animation, and in the Edge's last frame, i am calling an init function in my Javascript code that builds the test and creates the sprites. Some animation keeps occurring indefinitely in the background (sun and clouds) through the Edge code.

The problem is that the screen sometimes loads correctly and sometimes stops in the middle of execution. Through console.log, I discovered that sometimes there is an error event in Edge that sends a message to the console:

> Javascript error in event handler! Event Type = timeline

After that, all Javascript code stops and the screen is rendered useless.

I tried catching the error event and clearing it, by adding the following code to the head section of the index file:

```
function noError(){return true;}
window.onerror = noError;
```

but it didn't work.

I went into the Adobe Edge **edge.0.1.7.min.js** file and added a ***return true;*** but that didn't work either.

There is not much help on Adobe Edge issues, but there seem to be quite a lot of them...

the project can be seen at:

http://www.totalliberty.com/cet/farm/

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem and it was a jQuery conflict, i was loading it in the index and then edge was loading it in edgePreload.js. So the solution is to load all js scripts from edgePreload.js which looks like below:

```
 aLoader = [
{ load: "js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"},
{ load: "js/jquery.flexslider-min.js"},
{ load: "js/jquery.foundation.reveal.js"},
{ load: "edge_includes/edge.1.5.0.min.js"},
{ load: "Untitled-1_edge.js"},
{ load: "Untitled-1_edgeActions.js"}];
```

Answer (score 0):

In Adobe Edge Animate 2015 just add (+) your JavaScript link/links to the Library of your project.

(e.g. https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js)

[image]